# Circuit diagram for ACS712 and ZMPT101B with ESP8266 using ADS1115

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

This is probably a cry for help for a circuit diagram which involves connecting ESP8266 with ADS1115 with ACS712 and ZMPT101B(voltage sensor). Since both of them uses analog pins, and using a diode separator is not a proper idea in real-life. Therefore I ended up using the ADS1115 for more analog pins, which should be working fine. I am not a electrical engineer so I am having real trouble as to how to fix all Four of them together. Can any one help me with a circuit diagram for this? Any links or research papers links, etc. Thanks

Comment: I hope you have modules not bare chips. Add links. The ADS1115 use I2C a.k.a. Wire to communicate with MCU. Default Wire pins on esp8266 are io 5 SCL and io4 SCA. I recommend to use this pins. Of course te module needs 3.3 V and ground.

Comment: If you can make your comment as an answer then I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADS1115 use I2C a.k.a. Wire to communicate with MCU. Default Wire pins on esp8266 are io 5 SCL and io4 SCA. I recommend to use this pins. Of course the module needs 3.3 V and ground.

Answer (score 1):

Step one is to get the ADC working.  Once that is done everything else will fall pretty much into place.

The ADC you have chosen is an I2C device.  The ESP8266 doesn't have I2C as such, but it does provide a software-emulated I2C implementation.  This can be used on any pair of pins, but the default ones are GPIO4 for the data (SDA) and GPIO5 for the clock (SCL) (this corresponds to the Arduino Uno using pins A4 and A5 for I2C, so it should be easy to remember).

Once you have that working the wiring for the rest is the same as for any other system. The only thing that differs is that your analogue inputs are on the ADC chip, not the main module.

Here's a block diagram to get you started:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqv2lL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is assuming:

- Single voltage output from each of your sensor modules
- I2C pullup resistors provided by either ESP8266 or ADS1115 (add your own if not)
- All modules providing the required support components for the chip

Comment: ok, sorry i was inactive on this post, I did reply a comment to Juraj, dont know who deleted that.. Thank you so much for the circuit, I have been able to follow Juraj's instruction and come up with a circuit of my own. But your schematics help a lot as I am now confirmed that my circuit is correct. Although I am having another problem.But I will ask later, Thank you so much for the Help.

Comment: Majenko, can you share your code please

Comment: @LêHùng What makes you think I went to the effort to write any code? This is just a block diagram to show how it works.